# Project's StyleCop.Analyzers Ruleset appears in other solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2017, stylecop

We are trying to create a custom ruleset for our company based on the default ones from Microsoft, but with some of the more contentious ones disabled. This works fine. StyleCop.Analysers works great, and warnings and errors are created appropriately. It even works on our build server.

However... the ruleset I add to ProjectA in Solution1 is listed in the droplist of rulesets for ProjectB in Solution2. This is a problem. If I select this ruleset, then it will work locally but when I check it in nobody else will have this same path. As we want to deliver these rulesets by nuget, all the company rulesets will have the same name and be indistinguishable from each other. So even if you mean to, it's really hard to find the right one that is in your current solution.

This clearly sucks, and I cannot believe it's the intended mode of operation. What have I missed? Is there a flag in the ruleset that makes it locally scoped rather than machine-wide? Microsoft support you creating rulsets within a project, so why are they then available in unrelated solutions?

Do I need to work around this and install them once as a VS extension? This seems ridiculously complicated for a text file. Is this a bug in VS2017?

Any pointers greatly appreciated

-- Update --

I can install rulset's here:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets"

They will be picked up by VS2017. That's great, but now if I try to build on the build server it won't have the files, plus people's machines may have different versions. This is a total mess.

I need to be able to add a ruleset to a solution and use it within that solution - no-further.

-- Further Update --

Looks like it's the editor that is flakey. If you load a ruleset up, it adds it to some internal list it maintains. Whenever you then go to the droplist of available rulesets, it shows you the ones it's seen that are still available.

Answer (score 2):

So (unless anyone knows better), it would seem like this process is broken atm in vs2017. My workaround is to add the namespace of the project the nuget package is getting deployed to in the ruleset name. This doesn't stop the duplication in the droplists, but it means you can actually tell the difference and pick the right copy of the ruleset.

How to transform the rulset on NuGet install? add ".pp" to the end of the filename, and the file will be parsed for placeholders. So in this case my "Test.ruleset.pp" file will have a node thus:

```
<RuleSet Name="$rootnamespace$ Recommended Debug RuleSet" Description=" " ToolsVersion="15.0">
```

Yes this is rather verbose as names goes, go complain at Microsoft that their ruleset process is broken.

Other placeholders can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vslangproj.projectproperties_properties.aspx